# How to call a method comming from a UserControl and trigger the method in a Form which is a child form??

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, methods, user-controls

Senario:

`SwitcherForm` is the Main Form

`frmCategory` a Child Form

`ItemView` is a UserControl

What i'm trying to do is I want trigger or execute the method `refreshComboBox()` in the form `frmCategory` from the UserControl `ItemView`.

The UserControl `ItemView` contains the method `refreshComboBox()`.

```
public void refreshComboBox()
    {
        //some codes here
    }
```

And this is how I execute `refreshComboBox()` in `frmCategory`.

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        itemView.refreshComboBox();
    }
```

But it didn't work, the method did not excecute. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: can you show us your btnOk_click event binding ?

Comment: put break point in btnOk_Click event and check heating or not?

Comment: what do you mean event binding Muds?

Comment: Mr. Jamaxack I already added break in btnOk_Click event it pauses the program where the break point is located.

Comment: @Marley, when you want to notify a user on this website, please add an `@` symbol *before* their name as I did before your name in this comment. Then, that user will receive a notification that you have mentioned them.

Comment: Regarding your question, what is the relationship between `frmCategory` and `ItemView`?